# How to implement an odata wcf web api end point over a generic data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a program that queries any number of sql based datasources and returns the data as a datatable.  The name of the query and the parameters being passed determine the exact structure of the data returned.

I now have exposed some of this functionality via a wcf web-api end point.

I would like to know, is there a way of this being an odata end point that dynamically returns rows from the data table as poco's?

something like:

```
enter code here
[Queryable]
public IQuerable<dynamic> Get(string datasourceName, string view, string parametersAndValues)
        {

            var parameters =   ApiControllerHelpers.GetNameValueCollectionFromString(parametersAndValues);


            var ds = datasourceRepository.FindDatasourceByName(datasourceName);

            var dataManager = ds.GetDataManager();   


            DataTable dataTable = dataManager.DataTableDataRepository.GetDataTable(parameters, view);

            var dynamcicTable = dataTable.AsDynamicEnumerable();

            return dynamcicTable;
        }
```

With this setup, I get set of WCF data errors that complain about serialisation etc.. So I gues my question is, for odata support, do my classes have to be statically typed?